# How to prevent automatic JOptionPane YES_NO_OPTION confirm dialog box closing?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have created a `JOptionPane` and it has only two buttons `YES_NO_OPTON`. After `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` pops out, if user clicks YES Button then the dialog box usually disappears. But I want to prevent it from closing if a user presses YES Button. It will disappear only when the user clicks NO Button.

```
int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Press YES to continue?", "Click a Button", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

 if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
         CDUtils.open("F:\\");// Calls a method to do some work
        // Prevent Dialog Box from closing
    }
    else(dialogResult == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
             System.exit(0);
            // Close the Dialog Box 
        }
```

Comment: (1-) What is the point of having a YES option if it doesn't do anything?  How does the user confirm they want to continue? Don't use the YES_NO option, Just use the NO option. in any case if the "if statement" is executed it means the dialog has already been closed so it is too late to stop it from closing.

Comment: The point of using a JOptionPane is to display a message or get a piece of data from the user and then close the option pane. If you want to do something more complex then create your own modal JDialog and you can control the process and closing of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane does not support this. The buttons it generates always have `BasicOptionPaneUI$ButtonActionListener` as the sole listener, which just sets the "value" that the pane returns, which also fires a property change that closes the dialog.

What you could do instead is create your own `JButton` and pass that (or a `JPanel` containing it) to `JOptionPane` as the "message" parameter. It'll be above the row of `JOptionPane` buttons, though.